# Rownum in mysql with inner join

Tags: mysql, inner-join, rownum

i need to add rownum column int below mentioned code, please advice:

```
SELECT TE.ID,
       TE.QUESTION,
       TE.A,
       TE.B,
       TE.C,
       TE.D,
       TE.E,
       TE.QUESTION_TYPE,
       TE.SCORE,
       S.NAME AS Subject,
       TE.CREATE_DAY,
       TE.CORRECT
FROM TEST_TABLE TE
INNER JOIN SUBJECT S ON S.ID = TE.SUBJECT
WHERE TE.ACTIVE =1
  AND S.ACTIVE =1 LIMIT 1,1;
```

Comment: You're fetching only one row (due to the LIMIT clause (without any order by -- so any one row)). Why do you need to add rownum? that's just 1 for one row. right?

Comment: i will  call this code  in web page as pagination and i want to show user number of question. limit 1,1 = question #1, limit 2,1 = question #2, limit  3,1 = question#3....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code

```
    SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num,
       TE.ID,
       TE.QUESTION,
       TE.A,
       TE.B,
       TE.C,
       TE.D,
       TE.E,
       TE.QUESTION_TYPE,
       TE.SCORE,
       S.NAME AS Subject,
       TE.CREATE_DAY,
       TE.CORRECT
     FROM TEST_TABLE TE
    INNER JOIN SUBJECT S ON S.ID = TE.SUBJECT,
   (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
   WHERE TE.ACTIVE =1
   AND S.ACTIVE =1 LIMIT 1,1;
```